# A Java date parser which reads all British date formats

Tags: java, date, parsing

In my country, we use British date formats. Does a parser which can convert a date string written using any form of British date formats to a valid Java date object?

Comment: What's wrong with the [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)?

Comment: I think one of the Apache Commons libraries has a utility method which will allow you to pass it a `String` and a list of formats for it to try, it will return back either the `Date` object or `null` or an `Exception` if it can't find a valid match. This is likely the best you're going to get

Comment: a) You need to tell it what format you are expecting.
b) It prioritizes US date formats over UK ones.
c) A better option is Apache's date utils but you still need to provide all possible date formats.

Comment: @LeonidGlanz My question has a different focus. I want to be able to parse a variety of possible date formats. The question that you are talking about is more general.

Comment: @SandahAung Why do you think it prioritizes US date formats over UK ones? It will by default use whichever date format is appropriate for the default Locale.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am using Apache Commons now but users are keying in dates with formats we haven't covered but the formats they use do make sense.

Comment: Then you need to start building a list/database of valid formats you are likely to want to use and keep it growing, otherwise limit what the users can enter

Comment: You could use different regular expression in a map and take from that your SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: "*any form* of British date formats". Do you have a complete list, or are you thinking more dynamic?

Comment: @Andreas Do you mean I need to set the locale to UK? My country's locale isn't supported by `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: The parser should support any date format we can imagine and even the ones we haven't thought about but still make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From comment:

> The parser should support any date format we can imagine and even the ones we haven't thought about but still make sense.

That means things like:

```
14/3/2011
14/03/2011
14/3/11
14 March 2011
14th March 2011
2011-03-14
2011-3-14
March 14, 2011 (just for kicks)
the Fourteenth of March, 2011 (ok, maybe not this one)
NOT: 3/14/2011
```

If you want to support all of these, you have two options:

1. Iterate through a list of specific formats, until one works.
2. Write your own custom parser using regular expressions.

Writing your own custom parser makes it easier to support weird variants, if needed.